# Change options_for_select to radio buttons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, haml

Hi i'm trying to change the following:

```
  .form-group
    = label_tag :metric, 'Metric', class: 'sr-only'
    = select_tag :metric, options_for_select(Report::METRICS, selected: @report.metric), class: 'form-control'
```

to something like the following:

```
.form-group.pull-left
        = label_tag :metric, 'Metric', class: 'sr-only'
        .btn-group{"data-toggle" => "buttons"}
          %label.btn.btn-default.active
            %input#option1{name: "options", type: "radio", value: "value1"}/
            Value1
          %label.btn.btn-default
            %input#option2{name: "options", type: "radio", value: "value2"}/
            Value2
```

However the problem is that when I submit the form, it doesn't actually submit the radio button value. Also after it submits, it defaults back to no selection when it should remain on the selected radio button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`radio_button_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-radio_button_tag) helper and set the `checked` parameter correctly.

Using your example, it's something like this:

```
.form-group.pull-left
  = label_tag :metric, 'Metric', class: 'sr-only'
    .btn-group{"data-toggle" => "buttons"}
      %label.btn.btn-default.active
        = radio_button_tag('options', 'value1', params[:options] == 'value1')
        Value1
      %label.btn.btn-default
        = radio_button_tag('options', 'value2', params[:options] == 'value2')
        Value2
```

Comment: this is pretty close. it will still make the first radio button active when the page reloads event though the :options is reflecting something else on the page now

Comment: I think we need to somehow dynamically assign the `.active` class to the button that got submitted with the form. any thoughts on how to do that?

Comment: actually figured this out - just using the `addClass()` from js side.